# Confused with multiple Join in single query, Sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I am trying to join three tables in a single query in SQLAlchemy specifically but unable to do so.
I have done this so far :-

```
Test.query.join(Test.sections).join(QuestionSection.section).all()
```

I know it is wrong but I am trying to do it in a single query.

Here are my tables :-

Question section Model :-

```
class QuestionSection(Dictifiable, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'question_section'

    section_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('section.id'), primary_key=True)
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('question.id'), primary_key=True)

    question = db.relationship('Question', backref='question_section')
    section = db.relationship('Section', backref='question_section')
```

Section Table :-

```
class Section(Dictifiable, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'section'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('section_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    test_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('test.id'))
    name = Column(String(50))

    test = relationship("Test", back_populates="sections")

    questions = db.relationship('Question',
                                secondary='question_section')
```

And Test table :-

```
 id = Column(Integer, Sequence('test_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

    sections = relationship("Section", back_populates="test")
    tests = relationship("Corporate", secondary='corporate_test',
                         back_populates='tests')
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood what I was doing wrong, I should join like this :-

```
Test.query.join(Test.sections).join(QuestionSection, QuestionSection.section_id == Section.id).all()
```